# Are these 2 statements the same?

Tags: perl

Do these 2 statements mean the same thing?

```
if ($host eq '') {
    print "Host exists\n";
}
```

And

```
if (defined $host) {
    print "Host exists\n";
}
```

Comment: What kind of question is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they are different. One is comparing `$host` to the empty string, and the other is checking to see whether `$host` is defined at all (and may have any value).

Comment: I see, I though they were the same because when I would try the defined part it would not work and I thought I was something I was doing wrong. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

No.

If `$host` is `"localhost"`, they'll be different.

Comment: @Solignis: Yes, and if the variable `$host` has the value "localhost", then it will be defined, but not equal to "", so the two statements will produce different results.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you changed the first to:

```
if ($host ne '') ...
```

the two statements are not equivalent, as you'd see if you ran with warnings enabled and left `$host` undefined.

```
$ perl -we 'my $host; print $host ne "" ? "Hi\n" : "Lo\n";'
Use of uninitialized value $host in string ne at -e line 1.
Lo
$ perl -we 'my $host; print defined $host ? "Hi\n" : "Lo\n";'
Lo
$ perl -we 'my $host = ""; print defined $host ? "Hi\n" : "Lo\n";'
Hi
$ perl -we 'my $host = ""; print $host ne "" ? "Hi\n" : "Lo\n";'
Lo
$
```

Note that one of the answers is "Hi".  The empty string is a fine value; it is not the same as `undef`.

Comment: I see, I was just wondering because I am trying to make the my code as clean as possible.